# I want to control my motor using an arduino serial monitor

Tags: arduino

I want it to go "forward" if I type "forward" into the Serial Monitor and "Reverse" if I type "Reverse".

```
String readString;
int a = 8;
int b = 7;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Test");
}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(1);  
    if (Serial.available() >0) {
      char c = Serial.read();
      readString += c;
    } 
  }

  if (readString.length() >0) {
    if (readString == "forward")
    {
      digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(b, LOW);
      delay(5000);
      readString = "";
    }
    readString="";
  } 
}
```

If my code doesn't really work can anyone show me some simple examples of how to control a motor through the serial monitor please. I have searched on the internet for different examples, but they never seem to work and I cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is pointless to send full words like "forward" etc. or even to bother with using Strings in messaging. Just use -1, 0, 1 or chars 'r', 's', 'f' for reverse, stop, forward.

As for working out the communication syntax, there are good Serial examples which are included with the Aruinio IDE. Take a look at those.